# Device not receiving notification from CFM cloud function 2023

Tags: google-cloud-functions, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function on Google cloud (See below), when one device update receiver's "noti" collection under "users" collection on Firestore, the cloud function is triggered and send the receiver a notification. My cloud function console Log shows "Successfully sent message" with successCount: 1 and failureCount: 0. However, the receiver (user whose noti collection is being updated) not receiving any message. The device has the notification enabled. What are some possible reasons that cause the result?:

```
exports.sendNotificationOnNewDocument = functions.firestore
.document("users/{userId}/noti/{notificationId}")
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
// Get the user ID and notification data
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const notificationData = snapshot.data();

  // Retrieve the FCM token for the user from Firestore
  const userDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId);
  const userDoc = await userDocRef.get();
  const fcmToken = userDoc.get("fcm");
  const name = String(notificationData.name);
  const sku = String(notificationData.sku);
  console.log("check name:", name);
  console.log("check fcmToken:", fcmToken);
  console.log("check sku:", sku);


  // Set the title and body based on the type value
  let title = "";
  let body = "";

  if (notificationData.type === 1) {
    title = "You have a New Follower";
    body = "A new follower " + name + " just followed you";
  } else if (notificationData.type === 2) {
    title = "You are removed from a project";
    body = "You are removed from project: " + sku + " by " + name;
  } else if (notificationData.type === 3) {
    title = "Someone joined your project";
    body = name + " joined your project " + sku;
  } else if (notificationData.type === 4) {
    title = "Project Confirmed!";
    body = name + " Project: " + sku + " confirmed. Time to prepare!";
  } else {
    title = "Check Out New Project";
    body = "Discover new AI project opportunities";
  }

  // Send the notification using the FCM API
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: body,
    },
  };

  await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, message)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
});
```